react file-pond svg image displaying issue
i am facing issue with displaying svg image in my react-file-pond library. is there any configuration issue ? waiting for reply thanks. https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/getting-started/installation/react/
here what i m trying to do:
`<FilePond allowMultiple={true} maxFiles={maxFilesLimit} server={{ process: ( fieldName, file, metadata, load, error, progress, abort ) => { const formData = new FormData(); formData.append(fieldName, file, file.name); formData.append("uploadPath", path || "");
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhr.open("POST", "/api/wasabi");

      xhr.upload.onprogress = (e) => {
        // progress(e.lengthComputable, e.loaded, e.total);
        const percentCompleted = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
        setCurrentFileUploadInProgress(file.name);
        handleUploadProgress(
          file.name,
          percentCompleted === 100 ? 95 : percentCompleted
        );
      };

      xhr.onload = function () {
        const serverResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        onUpload(serverResponse?.url || serverResponse);
        load(serverResponse);
      };

      xhr.send(formData);

      return {
        abort: () => {
          xhr.abort();
          // setUploadProgress();
        },
      };
    },
    // revert: (uniqueFileId, load, error) => {
    //   // uniqueFileId is the ID of the file we are reverting
    //   console.log("Reverting file with ID:", uniqueFileId);
    //   load();
    // },
  }}
  // ** FilePond options on edit
  // files={imageLinks?.map((link) => ({
  //   source: link,
  //   options: {
  //     type: "limbo",
  //   },
  // }))}
  onprocessfilerevert={(file) => onRemove && onRemove(file.filename)}
  maxFileSize={`${sizeLimit}mb`}
  acceptedFileTypes={allowedExtensions}
  onprocessfile={(error, file) => {
    onUploadDone && onUploadDone();
    handleUploadProgress(file.filename, 100);
  }}
  onaddfile={(error, file) => {
    handleUploadProgress(file.filename, 0);
    handleUploadProgress(file.filename, 50);
  }}
  // ** uncomment when needs validation in filepond
  // onupdatefiles={handleFileLoad}
  // onremovefile={(file) => file && onRemove(JSON.stringify(file))}
  name="files" /* sets the file input name, it's filepond by default */
  labelIdle='Drag & Drop your files or <span class="filepond--label-action">Browse</span>'
  className={"filepond"}
/>`

is there any configuration i want do ?
